# How to install conda packages built with conda build without uploading

Tags: conda

I have built a conda package with `conda build mypackage`. I did not upload it. I can see the result in `myenv\conda-bld\win-64\` as well as in `myenv\pkgs\`.

However if I try to install it using `conda install --use-local mypackage` it loads an identically named package from the public channels instead of using my own.

If I prevent access to the channels with `conda install --override-channels -c local mypackage` I get the error `PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are missing from the target environment...`

So the question is: How do I install my own package?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is seems to be really poorly documented but I found a solution in an old bug report:

```
conda install -c "%CONDA_PREFIX%/conda-bld/" mypackage
```